# NOT IN after LIKE not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find all the words on the last character in the request with the condition.

My query is:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `cities` WHERE 
(SELECT `name` FROM `cities` WHERE LIKE '%а')
AND
WHERE `name` NOT IN (SELECT `game_code` FROM `games` WHERE game_code LIKE 'qaZxsw2wewewqRRE')
```

But this still not work.

Comment: `AND NOT IN`....and *what* not in?

Comment: Looks like query syntax is wrong.

Comment: You miss parameters in where clause

Comment: You have space before the "a" is that intended?

Comment: I want to find all the words on the last character which is not in the query result

Comment: add the column you want to check game_code not in it before the NOT IN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `cities` WHERE 
`name` LIKE '%а'
AND
`name` NOT IN ('qaZxsw2wewewqRRE')
```

You don't need:

```
(SELECT `game_code` FROM `games` WHERE game_code LIKE 'qaZxsw2wewewqRRE')
```

since it will only return one `DISTINCT` value which is `'qaZxsw2wewewqRRE'` and this would not affect anything because it does not end in doesn't end in `a` (`'%a'`)

So really you just need:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `cities` WHERE 
`name` LIKE '%а'
```